# Scaling my components in my website issue

Tags: html, css, resize, css-position

When I resize the tab on my website, I face issues where the components inside don't adjust and they end up getting moved to different places. I was wondering how I could go about solving this. I tried changing my values from percentages to pixels, and switched from absolute to relative positioning but I'm still learning HTML so having some difficulty.

[Here is the link to an online IDE for my code:](http://tpcg.io/_23ELP0)

[my local host website so far:](http://127.0.0.1:5500/index.html#More)

If someone could help me out, it would be much appreciated!

Comment: Please read [ask] and consider updating your question. Your code needs to be _in the question itself_ **(not linked offsite!)**, preferably in the form of a [mre]. Also, we can't access your local host, only you can.

Comment: Your link to a localhost domain won't resolve for anyone but people on your network, can you link an image or a repo instead?